# Show this function is $0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-(x-y)^2}f(y) \, dy=0$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $f(x)=0$ for Lebesgue almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

This looks like a convolution type problem, but I don't see how to construct the scaling. Or probably there're other ways?

Comment: Take $g(x) = e^{-x^2}$. You have $f\ast g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x-y)f(y)dy$.

Comment: Yes? I see that, but then I'm not able to invoke Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: I know a simple way to do this when $f\ge0$ almost everywhere and $\int_{\mathbb R} f(y) \, dy <+\infty. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{2zy} e^{-y^{2}/2} f(y)\, dy$. By direct verification you can show that this is an entire function. The hypothesis shows that it vanishes on the real line. Hence it is identically $0$. Put $z=it$, $t$ real, to see that the Fourier tarnsform of the function $e^{-y^{2}/2} f(y)$ vanishes. Hence this function itself vanishes, so $f=0$.

Comment: Just one quick question, I think your function restricted to real line is slightly different from what was given in the assumption.

Comment: OK, I see now, thanks!